# ng-show Angularjs not working when using CLI

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, angular-cli

I just scaffolded Angular app using `ng new app`. I want to conditionally hide some elements. I was trying to do it using `ng-show`. But it is not working.

```
    <span ng-show="false">Angular App</span>
```

Irrespective of what I put as argument to `ng-show` the element is always shown. Do I need to import anything or am I going wrong in some syntax?

Comment: are you sure you created an angularjs app and not an angular one?

Comment: Angular is different than angularJs, in Angular, they removed ng-show, you can use *ngIf="condition"

Comment: pls check for the angular version in version 2 or above it is different eg. <div *ngIf="userHasPet">
  {{ user.pet.name }}
</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Moshezauros and @Avinash Sharma for valuable comments. `*ngIf` does work well. `*ngShow` or `ng-show` does not work.

Now, the very important difference in `ng-show` and `ng-if` is that `ng-show` just toggles visibility whereas `ng-if` removes the element from the DOM. This has impact on performance in various use cases.

Thus, to have effect equivalent to `ng-show` in modern version of `Angularjs`, the `Angular`, you should use `[hidden] = condition`.

Use

```
<span [hidden]="true">Angular App</span>
```